# React "router-like" animations

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have a sidebar sliding menu that should act like a Router with transitions, but based on my app's state (redux) instead of routes.

The first time the menu is opened the transitions works fine. But, when I change between two inner components of the menu, there's no animations.

[image]

Here's the code for the component:

```js
const SidebarInnerPages = () => {
  const { selectedPage } = useSelector((state) => state.sidebarInnerPages)

  let inner = null
  if (selectedPage === "profile") {
    inner = <ProfilePage />
  } else if (selectedPage === "settings") {
    inner = <SettingsPage />
  } else if (selectedPage === "notifications") {
    inner = <NotificationsPage />
  }

  return (
    <CSSTransition
      in={!!selectedPage}
      unmountOnExit
      timeout={600}
      classNames={{ ...styles }}
    >
      <div className={styles.innerPagesContainer}>{inner}</div>
    </CSSTransition>
  )
}
```

So the first time the `selectedPage` is changed, the menu slides in just fine. But if I switch between `SettingsPage` and `NotificationsPage`, the latter just pops in instead of being animated.

I've tried wrapping the `CSSTransition` with `TransitionGroup` with no luck.

Any ideas how to go about it?

Thanks in advance :)